# Element reappears after hiding it by clicking a link (need solution that doesn't include return false or preventDefault)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element (DIV with a link inside) that i need to hide by clicking the link, and a form to show after clicking that link, the issue is that the link's `div` reappears shortly after hiding, if i use `return false` or `preventDefault`, it would work, but it would prevent adding the `href` value to the url, which i really need it to be added.

Here is code

```
<body>
<div id="categContainer1">
 <div class="titimmo"><a href="ajoutertest.php?c=realestate"        id="a_categ">Real Estate</a></div>
</div>

<div id="formContainer" class="hidden">
            <form action="ajouter.php" method="post">

                 <h4>Category:</h4>

                 <h4>Made :</h4>
                 <input type="text" name="made" />
                 <h4>Model :</h4>
                 <input type="text" name="modele" /><br /><br />

                 </form>
    </div>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function stepone(){
    document.getElementById('a_categ').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('categContainer1').className += " hidden";

    document.getElementById('formContainer').className = "visible";

    };
    }
    stepone();
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .titimmo {
      text-align:center;
        padding:10px;
        font-size:14pt;
      background-color:#CC3300;
      display:block;
    }
    .hidden {
        display:none;
    }
    .visible {
        display:block;
    }
    #formContainer {
      padding: 1em 0 1em 2em; background-color:#E8E8E8; margin: 1em 0 1em 2em; width:88.9%;
    }
    #formContainer h4{
      color:#FF3300;
    }
</style>
```

Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hr78f0wn/1/)

If it can be done otherwise, any help would be much appreciated, i just need the `href` value to be added in the URL.

Comment: You might be interested in URLs like `#realestate`, and using the `onhashchange` event to detect when the user goes back. This will allow you to save states without having the page reload on you.

Comment: do you really want only to hide the div on click of the link? as you have given a link to a php file as href. Be clear about it.

Comment: I'm working in a php file, it includes php code, html, and javascript, i just singled out those div s to show the example, should i change the file type or something? i'm trying to do stepwizard form on the same page, and need the href value to change depending on the link.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use history manipulation functions of Javascript.

```
function stepone(){
          document.getElementById('a_categ').onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById('categContainer1').className += " hidden";

            document.getElementById('formContainer').className = "visible";
          window.history.pushState('Form', 'My form',   this.getAttribute("href"));
          return false

       };
    }  

  stepone();
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much #Claudio King, your solution solved the problem. i just need to find a work around for on reload  it goes back to first state, and also when hitting back arrow in the browser it stays the same, Thank you again #Claudio King.